# Open Office Icons Missing

Tags: launcher, icons

I'm using 14.04 because 16.04 is still a mess.  I installed the Latest version of Openoffice SEVERAL times and no icons appeared in the Launcher.  I've searched and searched and have been unable to find an acceptable answer or, more preferably, a solution.

I've invested a lot of time on this silly problem...I've got it running from the command line but for heaven's sake, can I MANUALLY insert the missing icons? If so, how; failing that, is there some kludge that can be applied post install?

Comment: @Kyodake:  I already tried all of this.  I have main menu installed and tried it.  I even went through the trouble of writing the svg files and putting the icons in the /usr/share/app-install/icons directory.    I have successfully installed the OOWriter with the icon.  When I invoke "Calc" from the calc script , the same "Writer" icon shows and not the "Calc" icon.  This is true for the rest of the OpenOffice suite.  At this problem's  start, I checked the icon directory and didn't find any OpenOffice icons.  Were they omitted on the dwnload package?  I'm about to give up. Thanks anyway, Don.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
exec sudo -i
apt-get update
apt-get install alacarte
```

Open it from the Dash by runing `Main Menu`.

It shows the programs which are installed in the Dash.

You can do these operations from here:

```
-- Add or remove an application to launch from the Dash
-- Change the command used to launch the application
-- Change the icon
-- Specify if it should be launched from terminal
```